# In a list of dicts, update a value for the one element that matches a condition – without iterating

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've got a list (we'll call it `list_1`) that comes from a spreadsheet that is heavily array/index based, and I'm trying to compare it with another list (`list_2`) of objects from an API response.

> Worth noting that since Sheets is a multi-dimensional matrix, each row contains an array of columns (e.g., `row[0]` to `row[5]` for a 6-column sheet).

In order to make sure all the data matches up, when I'm iterating through `list_1` (performing some other functions), I then need to search for a matching object in `list_2` and update it with the spreadsheet's range.

I'm already iterating the spreadsheet rows (`list_1`), and the only way I've been able to do this is by iterating `list_2` each loop. That's pretty expensive:

```
for row in list_1:
    # Do some things with the row, then:
    for post in list_2:
        if post.id == row[0]:
             setattr(post, 'range', f'A{i+2}:F{i+2}')
```

I can write this with a generator expression, but (I believe?) that's still iterating, and still expensive?

```
for row in list_1:
    # Do some things with the row, then:
    setattr(list_2[next(i for i,v in enumerate(posts) if v.id == row[0])], 'range', f'A{i+2}:F{i+2}')
```

**Is there a way to update an object in an array by finding its value that's more performant than iterating over the entire list** or using the generator expression? For elegance' sake, it'd be swell if I could do it one line, but beggars can't be choosers.

If that isn't possible, please indicate so in your answer for completeness sake.

Comment: it seems the `list_2` elements each have a unique id. why just not create a dictionary of id:element for the list 2 items, then just subset accordingly?. Or to reduce the loop complexity, you could create a dictionary /hashtable whereby the id contains all elements of the same id. This will just loop over few elements instead of the whole list_2

Comment: This is pretty tough to provide a concrete solution to without an example of what the contents of `list_1` and `list_2` look like. The typical way to avoid iterating is to use a hash instead, meaning that instead of dealing with lists you need to transform them into either dicts or sets. The conversion is only a linear complexity instead of the exponential complexity of iterating.

Comment: I could probably refactor it to do something with that in mind, the trouble is that neither list is a subset of the other - some values overlap, and some are unique to each list. And until I write the values back to the sheet, I can't guarantee what the row range will be.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `list2` to be a dictionary which contains `post.id` as keys and `post` as value:

```
list2_dict = {p.id:p for p in list2}
```

and then you won't need to iterate over it:

```
setattr(list2_dict[row[0]], 'range', f'A{i+2}:F{i+2}')
```

Comment: In fairness, yes I could do that - and that probably solves more the root of my problem, but technically doesn't answer my question. I'm torn :)

Comment: @brandonscript why not?

Comment: Because technically the question was _Is there a way to update an object in an array by finding its value that's more performant than iterating over the entire list_.

Comment: @brandonscript your aim is to `NOT ITERATE OVER LIST2` this here provides exactly that.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without changing your data structure. Just out of curiosity, why it doesn't solve your problem? because `post.id` is not unique?

Comment: @Onyambu Yeah, and so I can accept this answer, but that won't help the next person who wants to know the answer. Assume `list_2` is part of a larger system and can't be converted to a dict... If it's _not possible_, then that's different, and this answer should call that out.

Comment: @Gabip it does actually solve it quite elegantly, it just doesn't directly answer the question I asked. I'm being picky, I know, I'm sorry, I just want this answer to be here for the future people who come along.

Comment: @brandonscript just create a hashfunction and use it to create the dictionary. Dictionary can be a thought of as a hash table

Comment: @Onyambu again - separating _solving my actual problem_ (yes, this works) and _the question asked_ because I want to make sure the next person who comes along asking this question can actually find an answer to the question asked, not how I solved it by working around the problem.

Comment: you should try to understand what @brandonscript is trying to put across. what if post.id is a list? an object of a class id?  ie cannot be used as a key in a dictionary? How would you go about that? He wants a generalized solution.

Comment: @Onyambu gotcha!